# SpringData findAll entries that were last inserted

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

suppose I have the following entries in the DB:

| id | entityId | entityPart | lastModifiedDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | entity1 | part1 | 28.12.2020 |
| 2 | entity2 | part1 | 28.12.2020 |
| 3 | entity3 | part2 | 28.12.2020 |
| 4 | entity1 | part1 | 30.12.2020 |
| 5 | entity3 | part2 | 31.12.2020 |

Now, if I want to use spring data to find the entry with the newer lastModifiedData field, I can find it by defining the following method

```java
findFirstByEntityIdAndEntityPartOrderByLastModifiedDateTimeDesc(String entityId, String entityPart)
```

Is there any way to return a list of all entries that will contain only the the entries that have the newer lastModifiedDate, so in our case it should return the list containing only the entries with ids 2, 4, 5, as for these entries, they have the newer lastModifiedData.

**EDIT 1**
As a solution I used a sql query like follows, also defined a fix for pagination

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM orders AS or WHERE LAST_MODIFIED_DATE =\n" +
        "      (SELECT MAX(LAST_MODIFIED_DATE)\n" +
        "       FROM orders \n" +
        "       WHERE (ENTITY_ID = or.ENTITY_ID AND ENTITY_PART = or.ENTITY_PART))"
       countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (\n" +
        "         SELECT MAX(LAST_MODIFIED_DATE) as or\n" +
        "         FROM orders \n" +
        "         GROUP BY ENTITY_ID , ENTITY_PART) AS order")
       nativeQuery = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the `After` keyword should be used:
(I kept the same ordering as in your example)

```
List<YourEntityType> findByLastModifiedDateAfterOrderByLastModifiedDateTimeDesc(Date lastModifiedDateAfter)
```

but, it will be not enough. First, you need to find the last one(with the query you've provided), and then query those entities that are with the value. This can't be done with one repository query, but you can combine multiple ones by defining a `default` method. Please note the `@Transactional` annotation, the queries should run in one transaction otherwise the result can be inconsistent.

example:

```
public interface ExampleRepository extends CrudRepository<YourEntityType, Long> {

YourEntityType findFirstByEntityIdAndEntityPartOrderByLastModifiedDateTimeDesc(String entityId, String entityPart);

List<YourEntityType> findByLastModifiedDateAfterOrderByLastModifiedDateTimeDesc(Date lastModifiedDateAfter);

@Transactional
default List<YourEntityType> findByLastModifiedDateOrderByLastModifiedDateTimeDesc(String entityId, String entityPart) {
    YourEntityType last = findFirstByEntityIdAndEntityPartOrderByLastModifiedDateTimeDesc(entityId, entityPart);
    return findByLastModifiedDateAfterOrderByLastModifiedDateTimeDesc(last.getLastModifiedDateAfter());
}
```

}

ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

Comment: yeah, but I do not have the lastModifiedDate parameter to pass, there may be different lastModifiedDate values for different entries, and I have to pick only the newer one

Comment: Now, I get your problem.

Comment: Would be useful to know what do you mean with newer, items with 1,2 and 3 as Id seems to have the same "lastModifiedDate". Why 2 should be considered newest?

Comment: @SimoneLungarella newer for each unique entry and by unique entry I mean the combination of entityId and entityPart, for ID2 = entity2 - part1, that is unique and there is only one entry =>this is the latest, for entity1 - part1 there are 2 entries, and we should be pick up only the newer one, which is ID4

Answer (score 0):

Because you use date without time there will be danger that you going to have duplicate date on entries. If you can modify database, just add boolean value it to identify latest entry. Then you can use List findByBoolean(Boolean true);

- you should consider to use epoch time for date to avoid later complications.